# Autopopulating data from the server to a textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a MVC application .net.

I have a textbox called "Products".
I have to autopoulate the textbox with the list from the server using jquery and ajax

Here is the code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Products,new {@id = "Products"})
```

In this textbox ,I need to call an action of a controller by ajax and get the data.

```
$('#Products).autocomplete()
{
    alert('kl');
    AutoCompleteDetails()
}

function AutoCompleteDetails()
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Student")';
    href = url;

    $.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: "json",
            data: AutoDetails,
            type: "POST",
            context: this,
            success: function (data) {

}
```

On the page load, the control is hitting Search action of Student controller,
I have two doubts here:

1. On page load, after hitting "Search" action I am binding the model values back to the page but    these values are not seen as dropdown as suggestions in the textbox called "Products"
2. After the page load, when I type "KL" and tab out the action "Search" of "Student" controller is not getting called.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the data to be populated as dropdown in the textbox after typing something in textbox?

Comment: Yes ,I need the data as dropdown

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Please fix the code in your question. There are some missing quotation marks, semi-colons, and brackets. I edited the formatting, but I couldn't touch the code, because it could be part of the problem.

Comment: Just check this link http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.in/2013/05/autocomplete-textbox-in-mvc3-razor.html .
Similar implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following sample, i think this will help:

```
$("#Products").autocomplete({
    source:
    function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: href, // Search Url Goes Here
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            $("#Products").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented same thing in our project.

Let me show you an example

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.MyData)
                                <span>
                                    <img onclick=" openAutoCompleteBox() " alt="click" src="../Content/images/dropdown_arrow.gif"
                                        height="19px" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
```

What I am doing in this is that I am trying to make it functional as Dropdown, so added an image at side of it , onclicking on it, it will call openAutoCompleteBox.

1. On page load, after hitting "Search" action I am binding the model values back to the page but these values are not seen as dropdown as suggestions in the textbox called "Products"

*For this what we have done is, we have loaded values at page load only and Autocomplete plugin will search value on client side only*

1. After the page load, when I type "KL" and tab out the action "Search" of "Student" controller is not getting called.

*You will not need to call controller, as Autocomplete plugin will take care of this*

I am not sure, if my implementation matches to your requirement but I calling controller again and again after a character will give your production server extra load. If you have static values then I would suggest it to load it at time when page loads. If its dynamic then your approach is fine.

Updated code for OpenAutoComplete

```
var sState = $(".jsonSuggestResults").is(":visible");

    function openAutoCompleteBox() {

        if (sState) {
            $(".jsonSuggestResults").hide();
            sState = false;
        } else {
            var valCrime = $("#Filter_dropdown").val();
                      sState = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi,I have couple of doubts here,               1.Should I install any plugins, I guess "Autocomplete" is a pugin.                   2.On click you are calling a function called "openAutoCompleteBox()" any implementation available for this ...i.e.,what does this function contain

Comment: Yes, we are using Autocomplete and we have customized it as per needed. Played around with Jquery. OpenAutoComplete box just opens dropdown. Here is the url : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I guess openAutoCompleteBox() is the code which fetchs the data by making ajax call to the controller ,right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use jQueryUI autocomplete plugin, i have been using it for a very long time and its simple and fun. Here is the url
[jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Check additional functionalities as well.